# Transferring to another university due to discrimination/policies/healthcare availability?

Tags: phd, transfer-student, harassment

I've read some threads on transferring to another university based on many factors, but mine are focused around my ability to live comfortably with workplace protections, opportunities, and medical care (among other things).

I'm fairly certain that if I laid out my concerns with my department, they would understand and be supportive (although I have no plans to do this as of yet). My question is essentially whether another university would be willing to accept my transfer for these reasons, especially this late in the game (year 2, recently finished qualifiers).

Would personal safety and access to resources be considered a respectable choice? I just don't want to shoot myself in the foot in terms of having a future, I suppose.

(Apologies if this has been posted before in some respect, also please let me know if this breaks any rules, this is my first question on this Stack!)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that in most places a transfer would be based entirely on you academic qualifications and record. While individuals may be sympathetic to your problems, most systems are too bureaucratic to include such factors in decision making. If you have a good record and have a promising future you can probably move.

In an interview, however, you could raise some issues, especially better health care opportunities, but I'd be a bit cautious about claiming a discriminatory environment unless there is already public discussion of some incidents. It isn't that such things are unlikely to exist, but that they are hard to judge and probably wouldn't overcome academic deficiencies if there are any. Just be cautious.

But you might explore your current situation with a trusted faculty member or with an office dedicated to student support before you make firm decisions.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, some is institutional, but not all of it is (some of it boils down to location). And yeah, I wouldn't make a claim like that lightly. I believe I'm doing fairly well (publications, conference presentations, 4.0 GPA, etc.) so hopefully that would be acceptable. (Thanks for taking the time to comment! It means a lot!)